# Set up a system of Linear Equations for an 8 cable tension problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to solve for Tensions in a set of cables using Linear Algebra and am running into some trouble. The problem is described below.

There are 8 pulleys at fixed positions holding a mass in place at a position (x,y,z) (z is vertical).

I have the pulley positions in space and the mass of the mass.
pulleys = {
"pulley_a": [1155, -2825, 2510],
"pulley_b": [-1155, 2825, 2495],
"pulley_c": [1155, 2825, 2495],
"pulley_d": [-1155, -2825, 2510],
"pulley_e": [1155, 2825, 2510],
"pulley_f": [-1155, -2825, 2495],
"pulley_g": [1155, -2825, 2495],
"pulley_h": [-1155, 2825, 2510]
}

mass = 1
This should be solvable but none of my research has delivered a solution for a problem with this many cables.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: With just two pulleys, their positions alone cannot tell you the tension on the pulley. Intuitively: you can pull on a rope at both ends with a lot of force or very little force. In both cases, the rope is stationary.

Comment: Would you mind to write the equations tou want to solve ?